# Warning message: In mean.default(data_subset, na.rm = TRUE) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Tags: r, mean, subset

The following code returns an error and I'm not sure what to look at first.  It appears the problem is in the mean function, but when I run the same function in the console a result is returned.

```
   pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
  data_files_full <- list.files("directory", full.names = TRUE)
  tmp <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(data_files_full))

  for (i in seq_along(data_files_full)) {
  tmp[[i]] <- read.csv(data_files_full[[i]])
  output <- do.call(rbind, tmp)
  }
  data_subset <- output[id, "pollutant"]
  mean(data_subset, na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

I'm new at this and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  To help make a reproducible example, you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here: http://bit.ly/SORepro   -  [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://bit.ly/SORepro)

Comment: I would guess that what you have in `output$pollutant` is a string, factor or perhaps NA.  Maybe `pollutant` is spelled wrong or mis-capitalized relative to the file it is being read from.

Comment: I don't think pollutant should be in quotes in that line. Maybe the argument `pollutant` goes there. But I took that class almost a year ago. Stick with it though!